# MongoEngine returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm creating a basic flask web application and want to get some data from my mongo database. In my `views.py` I have that:

```
from app import app
from app.models import User


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world"


@app.route("/users")
def about():
    users = User.objects()
    return users.to_json()
```

`models.py`:

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from app import db


class User(db.Document):
    snp = db.StringField(required=False)
    g = db.StringField(required=False)
    card = db.StringField(required=False)
    phone = db.StringField(required=False)
    passport = db.StringField(required=False)
    group = db.StringField(required=False)
    meta = {'collection': 'User'}

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "name": self.snp
        }
```

When I enter `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users` I get `[]`. Find returns nothing but in my mongo database I have collection `User` with two document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6089d5d13dc15d0a2c5f607e"},"snp":"testov1 test1 testovich1","g":"f","card":"12345","phone":"8888888881","passport":"8888 48484848","group":"users"}
```

and

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6089d5fd3dc15d0a2c5f607f"},"snp":"testov2 test2 testovich2","g":"m","card":"1676767","phone":"88566768881","passport":"8888 234343434","group":"users"}
```

Connection to database is correct.
I'm new to flask and mongoEngine.

Answer (score 0):

If you print users, you will see a **list** of 'User' objects, Actually When you try to get all users with `User.objects()` , the result is of type   *<class 'flask_mongoengine.BaseQuerySet'>*, so calling `users.to_json()` is wrong since it is not an instance of class *User* .

But if you get only one user with something like `User.objects().first()`, the result would be of type "User", and then you can call user.to_json().